# Only extracting text from this element, not its children

Tags: python, parsing, text, beautifulsoup

I want to extract only the text from the top-most element of my soup; however soup.text gives the text of all the child elements as well:

I have

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<html>yes<b>no</b></html>')
print soup.text
```

The output to this is `yesno`. I want simply 'yes'.

What's the best way of achieving this?

**Edit**: I also want `yes` to be output when parsing '`<html><b>no</b>yes</html>`'.

Comment: BeautifulSOAP has been removed. To get text of current element only in bs4, refer to @Horst Miller's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31909680/4428377)

Comment: The top answers are still valid without BeautifulSOAP. `.find(text=True, recursive=False)` feels cleaner than the `contents` list comp and type check.

Comment: Note that `text` argument to `find` functions is now deprecated. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76494168/1719931)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern (as of 2023-06-17) BeautifulSoup4, given:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
node = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
    <div>
        <span>A</span>
        B
        <span>C</span>
        D
    </div>
</html>""").find('div')
```

Use the following to get direct children text elements (`BD`):

```
s = "".join(node.find_all(string=True, recursive=False))
```

And the following to get all descendants text elements (`ABCD`):

```
s = "".join(node.find_all(string=True, recursive=True))
```

Answer (score 94):

what about `.find(text=True)`?

```
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSOAP('<html>yes<b>no</b></html>').find(text=True)
u'yes'
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSOAP('<html><b>no</b>yes</html>').find(text=True)
u'no'
```

**EDIT:**

I think that I've understood what you want now. Try this:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSOAP('<html><b>no</b>yes</html>').html.find(text=True, recursive=False)
u'yes'
>>> BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSOAP('<html>yes<b>no</b></html>').html.find(text=True, recursive=False)
u'yes'
```

Comment: In the second case (where the `no`, still in `b` tags comes first) I still want the output to be `yes`.

Comment: @jbochi Doesn't work for this `<h2><a aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="faqGen5" href="#">Is <span class="nobreak">XFINITY WiFi</span> secure?</a></h2>`. I need to get `Is secure?` for `find(text=True)`

Comment: @jbochi `text=True` is deprecated, `string=True` should be used instead

Comment: This was the accepted answer for 10 years. It was great at the time, but BeautifulSoup has moved on. Thank you very much @jbochi.

Answer (score 42):

You could use [contents](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#contents)

```
>>> print soup.html.contents[0]
yes
```

or to get all the texts under html, use `findAll(text=True, recursive=False)`

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSOAP('<html>x<b>no</b>yes</html>')
>>> soup.html.findAll(text=True, recursive=False) 
[u'x', u'yes']
```

above joined to form a single string

```
>>> ''.join(soup.html.findAll(text=True, recursive=False)) 
u'xyes'
```

Comment: Kinda works, but sadly doesn't help when the html is reversed: `<html><b>no</b>yes</html>`. I suppose I could iterate over the contents trying to find pieces that aren't tags.

Comment: `findAll(text=True, recursive=False)` thats my jam baby, especially the `recursive=False` bit!

Answer (score 16):

This works for me in bs4:

```
import bs4
node = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<html><div>A<span>B</span>C</div></html>').find('div')
print "".join([t for t in node.contents if type(t)==bs4.element.NavigableString])
```

output:

```
AC
```

Comment: more pythonically isinstance(t, bs4.element.NavigableString)

Comment: nice! be aware that your solution is more general than "find_all(text=True, recursive=False)" since it catch also text around a tag '<a>hi<span>J</span>so long</a>' you get 'hilong'. Instead with find_all just get the 1st: 'hi'

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into lxml's [soupparser](http://codespeak.net/lxml/elementsoup.html) module, which has support for XPath:

```
>>> from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
>>> s1 = '<html>yes<b>no</b></html>'
>>> s2 = '<html><b>no</b>yes</html>'
>>> soup1 = fromstring(s1)
>>> soup2 = fromstring(s2)
>>> soup1.xpath("text()")
['yes']
>>> soup2.xpath("text()")
['yes']
```