# Web scraper is scraping both text and <span> text </span>. Span text not needed

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Basically, I'm trying to scrape a table in python using [BeautifulSoup](http://crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

I've managed to scrape all the data in the other linked array, but for some reason when I add `.text`, it prints both the text and the text inside the span tag. The span text is not needed.

I've tried to do `.string` and `.text.text`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone spot the problem here?

Here is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.livefootballontv.com/').read())

for row in soup('div', {'id': 'tv-guide'})[0]('ul'):
    tds = row('li')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].text, tds[1].span.string, tds[2].string, tds[3].img['alt'], '\n'
    db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","","footballapp")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO TVGuide(DATE, FIXTURE, COMPETITION, KICKOFF, CHANNELS) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    results = (str(tds[0].string), str(tds[1]).text, str(tds[1].span.string), str(tds[2].string), str(tds[3].img['alt']))
    cursor.execute(sql, results)
    db.commit()
    db.rollback()
    db.close()
```

Then I am given

> Sunday 22 June 2014 USA vs PortugalBrasil World Cup 2014 Group G
>   Brasil World Cup 2014 Group G 11:00pm BBC1
>
> Tuesday 24 June 2014 Costa Rica vs EnglandBrasil World Cup 2014 Group
>   D Brasil World Cup 2014 Group D 5:00pm ITV

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children), and access the entry you want.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.livefootballontv.com/').read())

for row in soup('div', {'id': 'tv-guide'})[0]('ul'):
    tds = row('li')
    print tds[1].contents[0]
```

Output:

```
SV Hamburg vs Bayern Munich
Arsenal vs Manchester United
Napoli vs Roma
...
USA vs Portugal
Costa Rica vs England
```

Comment: I found a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children) btw. You can also use `find(text=True, recursive=False)`

Comment: The First one worked perfectly, thank you very much :) Top Geezer