# Parsing text in the same level as an html tag in beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this chunk of html I want to parse:

```
<div class="class123">
  <div><strong>title123</strong>
    <span style="something123">something else</span>
  </div>

  I want to parse this, how can do that?
</div>
```

How can I parse that with beautifulsoup? I know how to parse something inside a tag, but how to parse something on the same level?

```
soup1.find("div", class_="class123")
```

grabs everything inside the first div

Comment: What do you mean by on the same level? And, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AKS, .nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the div contents as

```
>>> from bs4 import NavigableString
>>> for x in soup.find("div", class_="class123").contents:
...     if isinstance(x, NavigableString):
...             print x.strip()
...

I want to parse this, how can do that?
```

The `content` will be list of the `Tag` and `NavigableString` objects contained within the parent.

Here `NavigableString` are strings which doesn't contain any sub elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to extract text contained in the element, not child elements or text contained in child elements.

You can use `.findall(text=True, recursive=False)` (see [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(
...     """<div class="class123">
...   <div><strong>title123</strong>
...     <span style="something123">something else</span>
...   </div>
... 
...   I want to parse this, how can do that?
... </div>""", 'lxml')
>>> 
>>> print(soup.find("div", class_="class123").find_all(text=True, recursive=False))
['\n', '\n\n  I want to parse this, how can do that?\n']
```

If there are multiple matching `<div>` elements you'll have to loop through them

```
>>> for result in soup.find_all("div", class_="class123"):
...     print(result.find_all(text=True, recursive=False))
... 
['\n', '\n\n  I want to parse this, how can do that?\n']
```

Lastly, you can tidy up the result to return a string

```
>>> print(" ".join([s.strip() for s in \
...     soup.find("div", class_="class123").find_all(text=True, recursive=False) \
...     ]).strip())
I want to parse this, how can do that?
```