# Python beautiful soup removing extra text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="friendBlockContent">
                Bartdavy<br>
                <span class="friendSmallText">
        Online
                </span>
            </div>
```

is the html, and I tried

```
 for div in soup.findAll("div", class_="friendBlockContent", ):
     print(div)
```

And this gives me if he's online, I only wanna get the name, how could I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` has two text node, you can access with `.strings` and use `.stripped_strings` to get clean data.
then unpack the two node with `name` and `online` field.

```
In [50]:  for div in soup.findAll("div", class_="friendBlockContent", ):
    ...:      name, online = div.stripped_strings
    ...:     

In [51]: name
Out[51]: 'Bartdavy'

In [52]: online
Out[52]: 'Online'
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to achieve this:

```
for div in soup.findAll("div",class_="friendBlockContent", ):
    print(div.contents[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code if you can make sure that the structure is similar to the one you posted:

```
for div in soup.findAll("div", class_="friendBlockContent", ):
     print(div.contents[0].strip())
```