# Text from BeautifulSoup4 missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to find the text inside the element ignoring the children text. So, I have used the following code:

```
text = """<a aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="faqGen5" href="#">aaa <span class="nobreak">bbb</span> ccc?</a>"""
obj = BeautifulSoup(text)
obj.find(text=True)
```

Expected output

```
aaa ccc?
```

Current output

```
aaa
```

Comment: How is `tag` defined?

Comment: Think my edit helps make this more self contained and obvious - feel free to roll back if not... thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31909680/6241235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) of a tag, you'll see that the text you want belongs to a class called [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = """<a aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="faqGen5" href="#">aaa <span class="nobreak">bbb</span> ccc?</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for content in soup.find('a').contents:
    print(content, type(content))

# aaa  <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
# <span class="nobreak">bbb</span> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
#  ccc? <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

Now, you simply need to get the elements belonging to the [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) class and join them together.

```
text = ''.join([x for x in soup.find('a').contents if isinstance(x, NavigableString)])
print(text)
# aaa  ccc?
```