# Extract text from div without attribute

Tags: xpath, beautifulsoup

I want to extract content (Content here) from following html with BeautifulSoap and XPath respectively.
How can it be done.

```
<div class="paragraph">
    <h1>Title here</h1>
    Content here
</div>
```

Output:

```
Content here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve that.Here are few of them.

By using `contents`

OR
By using `next_element`

OR

By using `next_sibling`

OR

By using `stripped_strings`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div class="paragraph">
    <h1>Title here</h1>
    Content here
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.find('div',class_='paragraph').contents[2].strip())
print(soup.find('div',class_='paragraph').find('h1').next_element.next_element.strip())
print(soup.find('div',class_='paragraph').find('h1').next_sibling.strip())
print(list(soup.find('div',class_='paragraph').stripped_strings)[1])
```

---

You can use css selector as well.

```
html='''<div class="paragraph">
    <h1>Title here</h1>
    Content here
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('.paragraph').contents[2].strip())
print(soup.select_one('.paragraph >h1').next_element.next_element.strip())
print(soup.select_one('.paragraph >h1').next_sibling.strip())
print(list(soup.select_one('.paragraph').stripped_strings)[1])
```