# How to use beautiful soup to extract only one element from a class?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape fundraising info using BeautifulSoup, and am running into trouble trying to isolate elements like the amount raised towards a fundraising goal.

Here is the code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import requests
import re
import json

page = requests.get("https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
Amount_raised = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0].get_text()
```

The code works, but when I view the result, it looks like this:

```
print(Amount_raised)
882,521 $ raised of 1,000,000 $ goal
```

Ideally, I would like to have just the number '882,521' returned or, even better, parse these into two variables, one with the amount raised and another with the fundraising goal.

I feel like there should be a way to either specify which element I want, or use regular expressions to isolate it, but my searches haven't been fruitful and I'm fairly new to python.

Edit: this is the section of HTML I am trying to work with

```
<h2 class="m-progress-meter-heading">882,521 $<!-- --> <span class="text-stat text-stat-title">raised of 1,000,000 $ goal</span>
```

Comment: `Amount_raised.split(" ")[0]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I found to do this is:

```
Amount_raised = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')
print(Amount_raised[0].contents[0])
```

prints $882,521

---

Found the solution here: [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with text which you get

```
Amount_raised.split(" ")[0]
```

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

Amount_raised = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0].get_text()
print(Amount_raised.split(" ")[0])
```

---

You can also skip `.get_text()` and then you can find and remove tag `<span>` from `<h2>` (using `.extrude()`) and next you can use `.get_text()` to get text from `<h2>`

```
item = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0]
item.find('span').extrude()
Amount_raised = item.get_text()
```

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

item = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0]
item.find('span').extract()
Amount_raised = item.get_text()
print(Amount_raised)
```

---

You can also get list with all `strings` in `<h2>` and then text from `<span>` will be as separated element on list

```
item = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0]
print( list(item.strings)[0] )
```

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.gofundme.com/f/eric-stevens-care-trust")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

item = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0]
print(list(item.strings)[0])
```

---

**EDIT:** other examples:

```
item = soup.find_all('h2', class_='m-progress-meter-heading')[0]

print( item.next )
print( list(item.children)[0] )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get both the goal and the amount actually raised, try:

```
amts = Amount_raised.split(' ')
locs = [i for i, x in enumerate(amts) if  "$" in x]
print('Amount raised: $'+amts[locs[0]-1])
print('Goal : $'+amts[locs[1]-1])
```

Output:

```
Amount raised: $882,521
Goal : $1,000,000
```