# Separating text before and after a <br>. (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
    div_tag = text.find_all("div", {"class": "team-name"})

    teams = []
    for a_finder in div_tag:
        team_tags = a_finder.find_all("a")
        for a_finder in team_tags:
            teams.append(a_finder.get_text("\n", strip=True))
```

This is some of the output:

```
    653
    NOSIDE
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="team-name">
          <a href="/team/653/2020">653<br>NOSIDE</a>
    </div>
```

The output is nice, but I would like to separate the team number and the team name into two separate lists. Ive been able to separate the text before and after the `<br>` tag using the `"\n", strip=True` params but I'm unsure how to actually separate the two into a list or var.

Any help would be quite nice.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put your markup as text in the question itself, not an image. See [why not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Beyond that, your output doesn't have much relation to the markup so it's hard to tell what you need. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)

Answer (score 0):

hey guys I was able to fix this by using the `.split` method, replacing the 
 tag with a `%` I was able to separate both sides into their corresponding arrays.