# Taking specific text from a div in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

here is an example of the html I am trying to extract from:

```
    <div class="small subtle link">                      
                    <a href="https://example.com" target=&quot;_blank&quot;  nofollow >Example</a>
                

                
                     This text!
            </div>
```

I want to grab "This text!" but I keep getting "Example" with it when I do this

```
                myText=soup.findAll('div',{'class':re.compile('small subtle link')})
        if myText: 
            extractedText=myText.text.strip()
```

How do I leave out the text that is in the a tag?

Comment: Have you tried `extractedText=myText[-1].text.strip()`  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)

Comment: @Sophia P Pls check out my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions, it all depends on the exact behaviour you're looking for.

This produces the correct output:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_src = \
    '''
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="small subtle link">
        <a href="https://example.com" nofollow="" target='"_blank"'>
            Example
        </a>
        This text!
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_src, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())

div_tag = soup.find(name='div', attrs={'class': 'small subtle link'})

div_content_text = []
for curr_text in div_tag.find_all(recursive=False, text=True):
    curr_text = curr_text.strip()
    if curr_text:
        div_content_text.append(curr_text)

print(div_content_text)
```

Edit: The [solution by Sushil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64673084) is quite clean, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
soup.div.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

Comment: this still grabs the "Example"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
print(div.a.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip())
```

This finds the `a` tag under the `div` and prints the text that comes after it.

Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="small subtle link">                      
                    <a href="https://example.com" target=&quot;_blank&quot;  nofollow >Example</a>
                

                
                     This text!
            </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

div = soup.find('div', class_ = "small subtle link")

print(div.a.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip())
```

Output:

```
This text!
```