# Parse an HTML element using the pyquery library or beautifulsoup. or a different alternative

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, pyquery

```html
<div1 class="tag1">
  <div2 class="tag2">
    <div3 class="tag3">no</div3>
    yes
  </div2>
</div1>
```

I want to parse div1 and I get its text if it has one
and I want to keep `{name_class: tag1 (or None), text: None}`,
and I reiterate: `{name_class: tag2  , text: yes}, {name_class: tag3 , text: no}`

My code to resolve this problem:

```py
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

a = '<div><div>no</div>yes</div>'
tryy = pq(a)[0]

tmp = [{"text" : tryy.text, "class" : pq(tryy).attr('class')}]
tmp + parse_rec(a)
```

`type(tryy) = lxml.etree._Element'`
But the problem is : `lxml.etree._Element.text` not keep "yes" contained in div2

I tried this but it does not work with bs4
[Only extracting text from this element, not its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)

All solutions whatever the library is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation the text "yes" would be considered the [tail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) of the element **div3**. Using your sample XML, the following code:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse("sample.xml")

for element in root.getiterator():
    print(f"{element.text.strip()}, {element.attrib['class']}, {element.tail.strip() if element.tail else ''}")
```

Outputs:

```
, tag1, 
, tag2, 
no, tag3, yes
```