# How do I search for specific text once I have scraped a website using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I scraped data from a Wikipedia page and am now trying to create a function that tells me if a phrase is within the results. When I do the command print(soup) I can clearly see that the word "December" is in the content but when I run the phrase through my function, it says it's not there. I have listed my code below and I can't figure out why it's not showing up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
def function(x):
    if x in soup:
        print("here")
    else:
        print("not here")

function("December")
```

Comment: please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995480

Comment: i understood that u want to check if some text is in a paragraph tag of the website, am i right?

Comment: @Dev Yes. Ultimately, if the phrase I am looking for is in a reference at the bottom, I want to be able to download the reference link.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use bs4, `if {string} in req.text` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have used the `text.strip` function to first convert the `soup` to string, because we should bear in mind that `soup` is in the format `bs4.BeautifulSoup`. As such, a string like "December" cannot be located from the content.

Please find below my take on it:

```py
import bs4
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen

page = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas")
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')

def function(x):
    if x in soup.text.strip():
        print("here")
    else:
        print("not here")

function("December")
```

which returns:

> here

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
if x in soup:
```

to

```py
if x in soup.decode():
```

Answer (score 0):

(As per your reply to my comment)To search for some text in the website you can use this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
def search(x,link='http://info.cern.ch/'): #default is the first website's link
    source=urlopen(link).read().decode()
    if x in source:
        print('Your text is in the website')
```

Comment: srry for late reply