# How to parse data from nested HTML tags with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the HTML using bs4. I get the following code and I need to put the text that goes after `<a>` tag and precedes `<span>` and the integer within `<span></span>` in a dictionary:

```
<a href="/somedata/10">
RSO <span>136</span>
</a>
<a href="/somedata/53">
3AD <span>53</span>
</a>
<a href="/somedata/343">
Lost in transition <span>2803</span>
</a>
```

I need to get to the following structure:

```
{
'RSO': '136',
'3AD': '53',
'Lost in transition': '2803'
}
```

I tried the following code and it worked fine until I discovered there were digits in the text.

```
tags = {}
for item in soup.select("a"):
            tags[''.join(x for x in str(item.get_text().strip()) if x.isalpha())] = ''.join(x for x in str(item.get_text().strip()) if x.isnumeric())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children). `[{x.contents[0].strip(): x.find("span").text} for x in BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").find_all("a")]`

Comment: That said, it's an antipattern to use a list of dicts that each have a different key format. I suggest using a list of tuple pairs, moving the keys to an outer dict and getting rid of the list (if they're unique), or use consistent keys per dict, something like `[{"name": "RSO", "num": "136"}, ...]`.

Comment: thanks! that helped. I will come up with a list of tuple pairs then.