# BeautifulSoup4 extracting extra text not shown in Element Inspector

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a script that tries to get a Twitter handle's name. Here's the script:

```
import requests, re, bs4, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20150623154546/https:/twitter.com/biz/status/600839913286672384'

r = requests.get(url).text
c =  re.compile('.*fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id.*')
user = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml").find("strong", {"class": c}).getText()
print(user)
```

Now, this is what the Element Inspector looks like:
[image: ElementInspector]

I want to print only the text highlighted above in yellow (`Biz Stone`). However, this is my Python output:

```
Biz StoneVerified account
```

As you can see, the string `"Verified account"` is appended, for an unfathomable reason. The text in Inspect Element only shows `"Biz Stone"`. Why does this occur, and how can I fix it?

I tried fixing it by following the instructions in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995480/18084172) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4995283/18084172). Unfortunately, the first one (adding `text=True`) printed random people's names, while adding to it `"recursive=False"` as in the second solution prints nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It adds `Verified account` because within the `Strong` tag is a `span` tag which likely has text within it somewhere that says `Verified account`

`.getText()` will get all the text within that tag

When I've encountered this issue, I've got the text from the `span` tag first then got the text from the `strong` tag and then replaced the `span` text with a blank string