# How to manage text in web scraping with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so I'm trying to learn web scraping with BeautifulSoup.

I'm facing small problem which is

```
<div class="teaserUnified__aside">
    <p class="teaserUnified__price" data-cy="teaserPrice">
              1 437 969<span> zł</span>
                  <span class="teaserUnified__additionalPrice" data-cy="teaserAdditionalPrice">
            10 490 zł/m<sup>2</sup>
          </span>
                  </p>
</div>
```

Theres a text in `<p>` and `<span>` inside . If i extract text from `<p>` I get both text together but I'd like to get them separated.

My result is

```
1199000zł5737zł/m2
```

and I'd like to get:

```
1199000zł

5737zł/m2
```

Or just `1199000zł` since other part I can get refering to `span`.

That's my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://gratka.pl/nieruchomosci/domy/wroclaw')
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,'html.parser')
all = soup.find_all('div',{"class":"listing__teaserWrapper"})
for item in all:
    item.find('p',{"class":"teaserUnified__price"}).text.replace(' ','').replace('\n','')
```

Is there any way using BeautifulSoup to separate this. I know  if I refer to span I will get my 5737zł/m2 but then if i want to get overall price from class text ill get also 5737zł/m2 value inside text.

For future learning. Is there any build-in function , when div contains text and other div/spans with text to obtain only text from main div ignoring other texts inside divs/spans etc or I have to handle this using python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only extracting text from this element, not its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separator` from `.getText()` and then chain `.replace()`, like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://gratka.pl/nieruchomosci/domy/wroclaw')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('div', {"class": "listing__teaserWrapper"}):
    sanitized = (
        item.find('p', {"class": "teaserUnified__price"})
        .getText(strip=True, separator=" ")
        .replace(" ", "")
        .replace("zł", "zł ", 1)
    )
    print(sanitized)
```

Output:

```
1437969zł 10490zł/m2
1199000zł 5737zł/m2
560000zł 6684zł/m2
2600000zł 10400zł/m2
1258069zł 9220zł/m2
1250000zł 9542zł/m2
3850000zł 12833zł/m2
4400000zł 7506zł/m2
1438494zł 10490zł/m2
4800000zł 13115zł/m2
2900000zł 8286zł/m2
880000zł 4889zł/m2
1025000zł 9343zł/m2
1200000zł 6349zł/m2
3633000zł 10749zł/m2
1357500zł 6170zł/m2
1500000zł 6881zł/m2
3650000zł 12167zł/m2
1750000zł 3267zł/m2
2599000zł 11107zł/m2
1280000zł 7758zł/m2
1750000zł 7955zł/m2
819000zł 3938zł/m2
819000zł 3938zł/m2
999000zł 4163zł/m2
1650000zł 4853zł/m2
2590000zł 6167zł/m2
3390000zł 17638zł/m2
2950000zł 7195zł/m2
2099000zł 11132zł/m2
1749000zł 8745zł/m2
2299000zł 11495zł/m2
```

Comment: And what if I'd like to extract only 2299000zł value from my tag ignoring other nested  tags text?

Comment: Split on `<space>` and take the first `[0]` item.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example you could use [`.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) to separate the contents and iterate the result to a 'list'

```
# select element and extract+strip all strings enclosed as generator
list_of_stripped_strings = item.select_one('.teaserUnified__price').stripped_strings


for item in soup.select('div.listing__teaserWrapper'):
    # select element and extract+strip all strings enclosed as generator
    list_of_stripped_strings = item.select_one('.teaserUnified__price').stripped_strings
    print(
        [
            first_string_of_pair.replace(' ','')+second_string_of_pair 
            for first_string_of_pair,second_string_of_pair
            #  create pairs - iterator generates a series of tuples containing elements from each iterable
            in zip(list_of_stripped_strings,list_of_stripped_strings)
        ]
    )

['1437969zł', '10490zł/m2']
['1199000zł', '5737zł/m2']
...
```

and if you need a single string, just `join()` the list elements:

```
print(' '.join([x.replace(' ','')+y for x,y in zip(e,e)]))

1437969zł 10490zł/m2
1199000zł 5737zł/m2
...
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://gratka.pl/nieruchomosci/domy/wroclaw')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    
for item in soup.select('div.listing__teaserWrapper'):
    # select element and extract+strip all strings enclosed as generator
    list_of_stripped_strings = item.select_one('.teaserUnified__price').stripped_strings
    print(' '.join([
        first_string_of_pair.replace(' ','')+second_string_of_pair 
        for first_string_of_pair,second_string_of_pair
        #  create pairs - iterator generates a series of tuples containing elements from each iterable
        in zip(list_of_stripped_strings,list_of_stripped_strings)
        ])
    )
```

Comment: I like your approach (+1), as it's very compact, but I guess the OP would benefit from an improvement in readability. What are `e, e`'s or `x,y`'s?

Comment: @baduker Thank you also for the suggestion for improvement, I hope I have clarified it to some extent and will see that I also take it to heart for the following answers.